# add element in certain place

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use document.createElement javascript will add an element at bottom of body.
How can I add an element in certain place ? (with document.createElement property, I mean store in a new variable)

Comment: `document.createElement` does not add the element anywhere by itself, you have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add dom/Element at the start or at the end of any DOM element using jquery.

See the below example

​

```
<!-- HTML CODE -->
<div id="item">
this is only test
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

JQUERY Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var item = "<span>New item</span>"
    /* PrependTo */
    $(item).prependTo('#item');

    /* AppendTo */
    $(item).appendTo('#item');


});
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

see the jquery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_div = null;
var newDiv = null;

function addElement()
{

  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newContent = document.createTextNode("test");
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);


  my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div);
}

</script>

<body onload="addElement()">
<div id='org_div1'> The text above has been created dynamically.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: down-voter .please take care to put reason for the down vote!

Answer (score 2):

> When I use document.createElement javascript will add an element at
>   bottom of body.

No, an element is returned, but it is not attached to anything.  You need to do that yourself:

```
var ptag = document.createElement('p');
ptag.innerHTML = "hello world";
var someplace = document.getElementById('some_element_id');
someplace.appendChild(ptag);
```

That's plain js; the jquery techniques are terser.

Comment: in jQuery it would be `$("#some_element_id").append($("<p />").text("hello world"))`

Answer (score 0):

uhm, I could be wrong, but if your using jQuery, are you looking for something like:

```
var newDiv = $("<div />");
```

Also if you have a jQuery list of elements (an object array) like `$(".divs")` which procs as `[[Object Object], [Object Object]]` (whereas each [Object Object] is a div element containing class `.divs`) you can add a new element to that list (without pasting to html body till ur rdy) by doing

```
$(".divs").add(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the element as a child of another one.

For instance:

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
...
[page content here]
...
</body>
```

JS

```
newdiv = $("<div>something</div>");
$("#container").append(newdiv);
```

See the [documentation of `append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)